# How do you convert US dollars to English pounds in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, currency

Is there a specific formula to use, or a shortcut on Google sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply by `GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:USDGBP")`